# Contar los valores que se repiten en una variable con condicion

Tags: r

Al trabajar con algún dataset, contar la palabra rojo en la columna color. Por favor si me pueden ayudar con un codigo sencillo

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia y carece de detalles, lo que provocará su cierre, lee [ask]

Comment: Bienvenido Luis a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero voy a crear un data frame, ya que no compartiste ninguno. sugiero que para próximas consultas puedas brindar más información.

```
set.seed(1000)
id<-sample(1:100, 20, F)
color<-sample(c("ROJO","AMARILLO","AZUL","NEGRO"), 20, T)

df<-data.frame(id,color)

# Aquí el data frame creado.

   id    color
1  68    NEGRO
2  43 AMARILLO
3  86     ROJO
4  51 AMARILLO
5  88     ROJO
6  29 AMARILLO
7  61     AZUL
8  18    NEGRO
9  22    NEGRO
10 45     ROJO
11 38 AMARILLO
12 33    NEGRO
13 41    NEGRO
14 95     AZUL
15 26    NEGRO
16 58     AZUL
17 55     AZUL
18 93     AZUL
19 37 AMARILLO
20 97     AZUL
```

Ahora como quieres contar cuántos de color rojo hay en la columna color. se haría con la condicional `==`. De la siguiente forma.

```
sum(df$color=="ROJO")

# que arroja el valor de:
3
```

Al colocar la condicional le preguntamo al programa cuales filas son iguales a ROJO, entonces el programa arrojará: `TRUE` y `FALSE`. Recordar que el valor numérico de un `TRUE` es igual a 1 y de un `FALSE` es 0. Por tanto al aplicarle la función `sum()` le decimos que sume los valores de la condicional. Y nos arroja 3, ya que hay tres `TRUE`.

Ahora puede ser el caso que tu vector no sólo esté la palabra `ROJO`, sino por ejemplo `ROJO CORAZON`. Entonces puedes usar la función `str_detect()` del paquete `stringr`.

```
sum(str_detect(df$color, "ROJO|rojo|Rojo"))   # Se especifica "ROJO|rojo|Rojo" porque la palabra puede estar escrita de esas maneras, si hay otras usted puede agregarlas.
```

Espero haya podido ayudarte.